# In Core data unable to store objects

Tags: ios, core-data

My code here i am trying to add list of object in to my array form that array i trying to add it to code data attributes.

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "model.h"
#import "coredataManager.h"

@interface ViewController ()
{
    NSMutableArray *entries;
}

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{


    entries = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    coredataManager *coreobj = [[coredataManager alloc]init];
    model *obj = [[model alloc]initWithContents:@"1" alternateLink:@"1" DownloadURL:@"1"];
        model *obj2 = [[model alloc]initWithContents:@"2" alternateLink:@"2" DownloadURL:@"2"];
        model *obj3 = [[model alloc]initWithContents:@"3" alternateLink:@"3" DownloadURL:@"3"];

    [entries addObject:obj];
    [entries addObject:obj2];
    [entries addObject:obj3];

    NSLog(@"%@",entries);

    [coreobj StoreValues:entries];



    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
```

my NSObject Class

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface model : NSObject

@property(copy)NSString *filename;
@property(copy)NSString *alternatelink;
@property(copy)NSString *downloadurl;

-(id)initWithContents:(NSString *)Fname alternateLink :(NSString *) ALink DownloadURL :(NSString *)DURL;

@end
```

NSObject Implementation File

```
#import "model.h"

@implementation model

@synthesize downloadurl,filename,alternatelink;


-(id)initWithContents:(NSString *)Fname alternateLink :(NSString *) ALink DownloadURL :(NSString *)DURL
{
    if ((self = [super init])) {
        downloadurl = [DURL copy];
        filename = [Fname copy];
        alternatelink = [ALink copy];
    }
    return self;
}


@end
```

Code to store in core data

```
-(void)StoreValues:(NSMutableArray *) sample
{
    Sample *value = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Sample"
                                                  inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    for (int i=0;i<sample.count;i++)
    {
        model *obj=[sample objectAtIndex:i];
        value.url = obj.downloadurl;
        value.filename = obj.filename;
        value.alternate = obj.alternatelink;

    }

    NSError *error;
    if (![self.managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Whoops, couldn't save: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }

}
```

But only the last value of the array is getting stored in the core data can any one guide me solve this issue 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before you save, you rewrite the object. Do this instead:

```
Sample *value;
for (int i=0;i<sample.count;i++)
{
    value = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Sample"
                                              inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    model *obj=[sample objectAtIndex:i];
    value.url = obj.downloadurl;
    value.filename = obj.filename;
    value.alternate = obj.alternatelink;

    NSError *error;
    if (![self.managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Whoops, couldn't save: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }

}
```

That saves the object after every iteration and doesn't rewrite it. Then starts anew.

Comment: The `save` should probably be done only after the loop for performance reasons (unless there are thousands of objects).

Comment: Right, create a NSMutableArray, store it there and then save it all up. You're right.

Comment: That's another step in optimizing :-) first step was to explain that iTag was rewriting the object everytime and that caused only the last one to save...